# Create empty file swift

Tags: swift, macos, file

How can I create an empty file in Swift code, preferably avoiding the Terminal, in as few lines of code as possible? I am using Swift 4, Xcode 9.4.1 and macOS High Sierra.
I have tried using the Terminal to run Bash code, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226934/create-file-in-bash-terminal-from-swift).

**Edit:**
The question this ones' been marked as duplicate for is for the *terminal*, which I am trying to avoid now, read that question (which I wrote) to see why.

**Edit 2:**
If the file already exists, I wish for the code to raise an error to the user, and the code will display it with NSTextField or UILabel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create file in Bash Terminal from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226934/create-file-in-bash-terminal-from-swift)

Comment: `FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)`

Comment: @LeoDabus: According to the discussion in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97497, `Data.write(to:)` is preferred over `FileManager.default.createFile(atPath:)`, because it takes an URL and throws an error in the failure case (instead of just returning a boolean)

Comment: @MartinR Thats what I usually use here. But thanks anyway

Comment: @LeoDabus: Although: they behave differently if the file already exists. I wonder why there is no `FileManager.create(at: URL) throws` method.

Comment: @Benj: What would be the intended behavior if the file already exists? Print an error message? Overwrite with an empty file? Update the modification date? Do nothing?

Comment: @MartinR I guess to display an error message to the user, UILabel or NSTextField style.

Comment: @Benj: I suggest to add that information to the question itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your script in the linked question, try:

```
shell("touch file.txt")
```

The command `touch` will create the file `file.txt`.

You do not need the terminal for anything here, just run your `.swift` file and you will have your file.

In case you need the file to write to, just use something like this:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "file.txt")
try "Some string".write(to: url, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```

You file `file.txt` will contain the string "Some string" in it.

**Update**

AFAIK it is not possible to just create a file, but you could create a file with an empty string:

```
try "".write(to: url, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```

As mentioned by OP in comment, it is also necessary to disable sandboxing: [Remove Sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018354/remove-sandboxing)

Comment: Needed to disable app sandboxing. Thanks!